Pandas rolling closest value
Suppose we have the following dataframe:
              timestamp      open      high       low     close  delta  atr  last_index  bearish bullish_turning_point
2   04-10-2024 01:54:44  18370.00  18377.75  18367.50  18376.00     32    0        1949    False                  True
5   04-10-2024 03:21:14  18376.50  18383.00  18375.25  18381.25     28    0        3899    False                  True
7   04-10-2024 04:38:54  18378.50  18386.25  18378.25  18385.50    133    0        5199    False                  True
9   04-10-2024 05:30:27  18384.00  18389.50  18378.75  18388.25    135    0        6499    False                  True
12  04-10-2024 06:06:12  18371.00  18378.00  18369.50  18378.00    130    0        8449    False                  True
14  04-10-2024 06:33:44  18372.25  18383.75  18372.00  18376.25     67    0        9749    False                  True
18  04-10-2024 07:21:14  18377.50  18387.75  18376.25  18380.00      8    0       12349    False                  True
22  04-10-2024 07:47:58  18388.00  18396.75  18385.25  18389.50    -30    0       14949    False                  True
25  04-10-2024 08:06:17  18390.75  18397.00  18387.50  18392.00    -25    0       16899    False                  True
28  04-10-2024 08:33:32  18384.75  18398.00  18383.25  18394.00     89    0       18849    False                  True
30  04-10-2024 08:54:35  18391.25  18403.00  18387.75  18399.25     84    0       20149    False                  True
34  04-10-2024 09:11:15  18388.75  18396.25  18385.75  18392.25     15    0       22749    False                  True
43  04-10-2024 10:02:22  18343.50  18350.50  18341.25  18350.50    113    0       28599    False                  True
46  04-10-2024 10:14:44  18352.00  18361.75  18352.00  18360.00    -42    0       30549    False                  True
49  04-10-2024 10:35:49  18354.00  18361.25  18347.75  18358.00     49    0       32499    False                  True
52  04-10-2024 10:54:18  18362.25  18372.00  18361.50  18372.00    180    0       34449    False                  True
56  04-10-2024 11:12:32  18369.25  18379.50  18367.00  18376.50     78    0       37049    False                  True
59  04-10-2024 11:27:27  18370.00  18376.50  18367.50  18373.25     54    0       38999    False                  True
65  04-10-2024 12:01:53  18377.75  18388.25  18377.50  18383.25    108    0       42899    False                  True
73  04-10-2024 12:25:04  18382.00  18386.25  18381.00  18384.75     65    0       48099    False                  True

How can I find the "nearest" close to "open" for each line before? E.g.
For line 30 (close: 18399.25) this would be line 25 (open: 18390.75). For line 52 (close: 18372.00) this would be 14 (open: 18372.25) and so on.

what is closest close? provide desired output of your sample.

@PandaKim: "Nearest" to every close row. Let me explain it further.

If so, try using expanding instead of rolling.

What if the nearest open is on the same day. Do you want that value?

To be honest, this is tick data (~500k rows per day) - open on the same day is far too inaccurate...

If you want to include the current row's open in the closest open values, you can do this:
df['nearest'] = [(abs(df.loc[:i, 'open'] - close)).idxmin() for i, close in df['close'].items()]

Output:
[2, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 7, 22, 25, 25, 30, 30, 43, 46, 49, 14, 5, 14, 9, 28]

If you don't want to include the current row's open, it gets a little more complicated:
df['nearest'] = [0] + [(abs(df.loc[:df.index[i-1], 'open'] - close)).idxmin() for i, close in enumerate(df['close'][1:], 1)]

Output:
[0, 2, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 9, 22, 25, 25, 30, 2, 2, 46, 14, 5, 14, 9, 28]

You can substitute np.nan (or anything else) for the value for the first row as desired.
The above code implements what is effectively an expanding window. If you want to implement a rolling window, you can use this code:
k = 5    # length of window
df['nearest'] = [0] * k + [(abs(df.loc[df.index[i-k]:df.index[i-1], 'open'] - close)).idxmin() for i, close in enumerate(df['close'][k:], k)]

Output:
# k = 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 9, 22, 25, 25, 30, 28, 43, 46, 34, 34, 56, 59, 65]
# k = 8
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 25, 25, 30, 12, 14, 46, 28, 28, 56, 34, 34]


Nice! TIL that you can do abs(pd.Series) :) +1

@AndrejKesely yeah, who needs the silly .abs()! :)

But seriously I find abs(...) a lot easier to read

Thanks a lot - this is similar to the expanding(...) mechanism, right? And if I would want to limit it to a sliding window, I'd simply have to adjust the for loop?

@Jan yes, that's an expanding window. I've edited my answer with code for a rolling window

@Nick: Very good, thanks a ton

Try:
def find_closest_value(idx):
    g = df.loc[: idx.iat[-1]]
    close_ = g.loc[idx.iat[-1], "close"]
    closest_open_to_close = (g.loc[: idx.iat[-2], "open"] - close_).abs().argmin()
    return g.index[closest_open_to_close]


df["nearest"] = df.index.to_frame().expanding(min_periods=2).apply(find_closest_value)
print(df)

Prints:
              timestamp      open      high       low     close  delta  atr  last_index  bearish  bullish_turning_point  nearest
2   04-10-2024 01:54:44  18370.00  18377.75  18367.50  18376.00     32    0        1949    False                   True      NaN
5   04-10-2024 03:21:14  18376.50  18383.00  18375.25  18381.25     28    0        3899    False                   True      2.0
7   04-10-2024 04:38:54  18378.50  18386.25  18378.25  18385.50    133    0        5199    False                   True      5.0
9   04-10-2024 05:30:27  18384.00  18389.50  18378.75  18388.25    135    0        6499    False                   True      7.0
12  04-10-2024 06:06:12  18371.00  18378.00  18369.50  18378.00    130    0        8449    False                   True      7.0
14  04-10-2024 06:33:44  18372.25  18383.75  18372.00  18376.25     67    0        9749    False                   True      5.0
18  04-10-2024 07:21:14  18377.50  18387.75  18376.25  18380.00      8    0       12349    False                   True      7.0
22  04-10-2024 07:47:58  18388.00  18396.75  18385.25  18389.50    -30    0       14949    False                   True      9.0
25  04-10-2024 08:06:17  18390.75  18397.00  18387.50  18392.00    -25    0       16899    False                   True     22.0
28  04-10-2024 08:33:32  18384.75  18398.00  18383.25  18394.00     89    0       18849    False                   True     25.0
30  04-10-2024 08:54:35  18391.25  18403.00  18387.75  18399.25     84    0       20149    False                   True     25.0
34  04-10-2024 09:11:15  18388.75  18396.25  18385.75  18392.25     15    0       22749    False                   True     30.0
43  04-10-2024 10:02:22  18343.50  18350.50  18341.25  18350.50    113    0       28599    False                   True      2.0
46  04-10-2024 10:14:44  18352.00  18361.75  18352.00  18360.00    -42    0       30549    False                   True      2.0
49  04-10-2024 10:35:49  18354.00  18361.25  18347.75  18358.00     49    0       32499    False                   True     46.0
52  04-10-2024 10:54:18  18362.25  18372.00  18361.50  18372.00    180    0       34449    False                   True     14.0
56  04-10-2024 11:12:32  18369.25  18379.50  18367.00  18376.50     78    0       37049    False                   True      5.0
59  04-10-2024 11:27:27  18370.00  18376.50  18367.50  18373.25     54    0       38999    False                   True     14.0
65  04-10-2024 12:01:53  18377.75  18388.25  18377.50  18383.25    108    0       42899    False                   True      9.0
73  04-10-2024 12:25:04  18382.00  18386.25  18381.00  18384.75     65    0       48099    False                   True     28.0


Thanks a lot - is there any advantage over @Nick's answer?

@Jan I think Nick's answer's more elegant. Pick one that suits you best (and is e.g. more efficient)
